# Which Abednedo are named after Beastie Boys titles?

Tags: star-wars, names, inspiration

Some Abednedo have been named after albums or songs by the Beastie Boys, most famously Ello Asty after *Hello Nasty*. The Abednedo themselves having been named after part of the refrain to "Shadrach" from *Paul's Boutique*.‡

Yet there are other Abednedo for which no corresponding Beastie Boys title seems to exist.

So which Abednedo are named after Beastie Boys titles, and which definitely aren't?

---

*This is a list question, but a limited list, which we typically allow.*

---

‡: The song "Shadrach" by Beastie Boys uses a sample of "Loose Booty" by Sly and the Family Stone, where Sly and the band chant "Shadrach, Meshach, Abednego". This in turn comes from the Bible, Daniel 1:7 "The chief official gave them new names: to Daniel, the name Belteshazzar; to Hananiah, Shadrach; to Mishael, Meshach; and to Azariah, Abednego."
However, with all the other Beastie Boys references, the name of the *Star Wars* species most likely originated as a reference to the Beastie Boys song.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Abednedo#Behind_the_scenes:~:text=.%5B29%5D-,Taking%20note%20of%20this,-%2C%20Lucasfilm%20Ltd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Named after Beastie Boys titles

- Awls Ooteek, after the album *Paul's Boutique*
- Brasmon Kee, after the song "Brass Monkey" from *Licensed to Ill*
- Ello Asty, after the album *Hello Nasty*
- Ilco Munica, after the album *Ill Communication*
- Oddy Muva, after the song "Body Movin'" from *Hello Nasty*
- Roodown, after the song "Root Down" from *Ill Communication*
- Sarb Iltage, after the song "Sabotage" from *Ill Communication*
- Slowen Lo, after the song "Slow and Lo" from *Licensed to Ill*
- Sowa Chuan, after the song "So What'cha Want" from *Check Your Head*

#### Unknown origins

- Antrot
- Arno Xan
- Bushar
- C'ai Threnalli
- Dazur Dar
- Durm Bormo
- Marn Kel
- Toomata Wree

Comment: "Toomata Wree" might be after "Too Many Rappers."  More speculatively, "Marn Kel" could be after "Biz Markie," another famous rapper that the Beastie Boys covered.

Comment: In case this connects for anyone, seems like C'ai Thenalli could sound like "Catherine Alley" and Dazur Dar could be "deserter" or "the shirt or" or something like that. Arno Xan makes me think "hard nosing". I couldn't connect any of this with Beastie Boys titles but maybe someone else will hear a link.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "C'ai Thenalli" would probably be from the sitcom *Kate & Allie*, although I known of no connection to the Beastie Boys except the 1980s millieu.

Comment: @Buzz there's an "R" in there, though: C'ai Threnalli.